# How do I know any image chosen from recyclerview?

Tags: android, json

hello i have this json data [a link](https://itunes.apple.com/jo/rss/topfreeapplications/limit=50/json)

and i parsing jsonArray into

this is a piece of json ,

```
"im:image":[  
           {  
              "label":"http://is1.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple20/v4/87/35/82/87358231-ce91-3d14-b306-95888c23db3c/mzl.gdgtivnk.png/53x53bb-85.png",
              "attributes":{  
                 "height":"53"
              }
           },
           {  
              "label":"http://is5.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple20/v4/87/35/82/87358231-ce91-3d14-b306-95888c23db3c/mzl.gdgtivnk.png/75x75bb-85.png",
              "attributes":{  
                 "height":"75"
              }
           },
           {  
              "label":"http://is3.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple20/v4/87/35/82/87358231-ce91-3d14-b306-95888c23db3c/mzl.gdgtivnk.png/100x100bb-85.png",
              "attributes":{  
                 "height":"100"
              }
           }
```

i pars it like this photo 
[image]

but when i click into any image here , i got just this image !

[image]

how i can solve this problem and when i click into "snapchat" i got image for snap ??

this is method that parsing json

```
 public void JsonAppShowData() {
    final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest( jsonUrl, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {  try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONObject(feedKey).getJSONArray(entryKey);
            AppShowModule appShowModule = new AppShowModule();
            int x = appShowModule.getId();
            for (int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length();i++)
            {
                JSONArray imageArray = response.getJSONObject(feedKey).getJSONArray(entryKey).getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray(imageKey);
                for (int j = 0; j < imageArray.length(); j++) {
                    String image = imageArray.getJSONObject(j).getString(labelKey).toString();
                    imageUrls.add(image);
                    appShowModule.setAllimage(imageUrls);
                    appShowModules.add(appShowModule);
                }}
                imageRecyclerViewadapter = new ImageListAdapter(appShowModules, getContext(), imageUrls);
                AppRecyclerView.setAdapter(imageRecyclerViewadapter);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }}
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e( "LOG", error.toString() );
        }
    } );
```

this is the image list loader

```
public class ImageListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageListAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    List<AppShowModule> appShowModules;
    List<String> imageUrl;
    AppShowModule appShowModule;
    String x;
    Context context;
    public ImageListAdapter(List<AppShowModule> appShowModules, Context context ,List<String>imageUrls
    ){
        super();
        this.imageUrl =imageUrls;
        this.appShowModules = appShowModules;
        this.context = context;}
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from( parent.getContext() ).inflate( R.layout.imagelayout, parent,false );
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder( v );
        return viewHolder;}
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        AppShowModule appShowModule = appShowModules.get(position);
         x = appShowModule.getAllimage().get(position);
        Picasso.with(context).load(x).into(holder.appImage);
    }
    public int getItemCount() {
        return imageUrl.size();
    }
    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView appImage;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            appImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.appImage);
            appImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent= new Intent(context, ImageShow.class);
                    intent.putExtra("image", x);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }});
        }

        }
}
```

and this is the activity that will display when clicked

```
appImage=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.appImage);
    Picasso.with(context).load(x).into(appImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly use the variable 'x' inside ViewHolder, as it'll not hod the image link of the item clicked.

To get the correct link you have to use **getAdapterPosition()**. If your click responds depends on the position of the item clicked, you can simply call getAdapterPosition() from within the ViewHolder. Beow i have shown how to use it in ViewHolder.

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnItemClickListener {
public MyViewHolder(View view) {
  super(view);

  view.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void OnClick(View view) {
  // Get the item clicked
  // For this example, I'm assuming your data source is of type `List<MyObject>`
  MyObject myObject = mDataSource.get(getAdapterPosition());
  // Then you can do any actions on it, for example - 
  myObject.setChecked();
   }
}
```

Comment: this code is into onBindViewHolder 
and i try to add getAdapterPosition()); to the view holder its connot reslove !

Answer (score 0):

You may define a callback in your adapter for the item clicked

```
public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClicked(YourItem item);
}
```

Expose a method in your adapter for the calling fragment or activity to set the listener

```
 public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
    this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
}
```

While binding yourviewholder , you may report the event back to fragment or activity & perform business logic

```
 @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) { 
        //your binding code
        if (onItemClickListener != null) {
          onItemClickListener.onItemClicked(item);
        }
    }
```

IN your fragment or activity

```
adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new YourAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClicked(YourItem item) {
                //Business logic goes here
            }
        });
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but what do you mean on this ? 

    void onItemClicked(YourItem item);

your item ??

Comment: IN your case AppShowModule is "YourItem" to the adapter

Comment: ok now the this.onItemClickListener  , onItemClickListener cannot be solve !

Comment: OK So, Call setOnItemClickListener from the ImageList . Now in your onBindViewHolder , pass the item that was clicked to ImageList (As AppShowModule would then contain the url you want for AppShow . Now from your ImageList throw an intent and pass url from AppShowModule to AppShow activity or fragment & then use image view to load the url contents for you using Picasso

Comment: thank you for your answer but this is the main problem to me i try this and its not working ,, please check this problem and try to tell me how i can solve it ,, again ! thank you 
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39495313/error-in-display-image-from-jsonarray-to-picasso)